# Horizontal line in css

Tags: html, css

You can see a thick blue line below the slider in http://nextrelease.officetimer.com/. How do I extend that line to the screen width. Please Help.

Comment: You have that element constrained within a parent with a set width.

Comment: Yeah i know that. but i can change it using inline styles right?

Comment: Nopes... That's not possible.

Comment: Change the page structure that it is a parent DIV!

Comment: @PraveenKumar: There are no other possibility?

Comment: This is not a very good question for StackOverflow. You shouldn't just put up a link to your site and ask how you can improve it. You should try to narrow down the problem, create a smaller example that doesn't have 1000 lines of code and still shows the problem. Furthermore, you should only ask here if you are stuck, if everything you have tried failed and you don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Mr Lister: Sorry i am new in developing still in training stage. Yes i do accept what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your elements are in the one container. so you blue line will extend to the outer container only. if you want to extend it further more, write the line outside the container. It is impossible to change using inline styles. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looking at OT.css of that site you can see that .customer_logo_slider_line has left and right margins of 18% and 19%;
just change the values accordingly.

Comment: did you try doing it?

Comment: yes, you can do it also: in Google Chrome right click on the bar and select Inspect element, and then - uncheck margins in debugger

Answer (score 0):

unset the width for `.wrapper` 
and add it to `.wrapper div`